# homogeneous differential equations 5

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hi how do i solve the following ODE
$$(x+y)y'= 3y-x$$given $y(2)=1$.

So here's what I was thinking this is non-linear but I can see it looks like a homogeneous first order ODE so fiddling around I get:
$$y'=\frac{3\frac{y}{x}-1}{1+\frac{y}{x}}$$.

But i have no idea how to do go ahead. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

substituting $$\frac{y}{x}=u$$ then we get $$y=ux$$ and we get $$y'=u'x+u$$
can you finish?
and you will get
$$\frac{du}{dx}x=\frac{-u^2+2u-1}{u+1}$$ this is separable
and now you can write
$$-\frac{u+1}{(u-1)^2}du=\frac{dx}{x}$$
does it work now?

Comment: sorry to bother you that isnt working for me i get $\frac{2}{v-1}-ln(v-1)=ln(x)+C$ which dosent work with my initial condition

Comment: should i post you the whole solution?

Comment: it is $$\log
   \left(\frac{y(x)}{x}-1\right)-\frac{2}{\frac{y
   (x)}{x}-1}=c_1-\log (x)$$ and can not expressed in the form $$y(x)=...$$

Comment: oh wait sorry that does work cause when you integrate you get the modulus signs don't you  okay thank you

Comment: yes you must write the modulus signs additionally